# How to make a tab-like or ribbon-like label on a QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qt6

What would be a good way to create a ribbon-like label for displaying text in a QGraphicsView which contains a QGraphicsScene such that the ribbon "floats above" the scene? i.e. is independent of the translation and other transformations of the scene and remains fixed at the bottom of the view.

I want to implement such a ribbon as a sort of status line to indicate when the application is in a modal state, but don't know if it's possible to do easily. (If it's not I'll think of something else) I don't need code just a general idea of how to approach this.

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind manually drawing it using the `QPainter` API, you could just override the `QGraphicsView::drawForeground(QPainter *, const QRectF &)` virtual method in your `QGraphicsView`-subclass to do the necessary painting.

Comment: Note that if you do that, you'll probably want to call `painter->resetTransform()` before doing the drawing calls, so that you can do your drawing in the `QGraphicsView`'s widget-coordinates, rather than in the default scene-coordinates.

Comment: thanks. I did this except with the scene not the view, which may be what you meant.

Comment: Both `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` have a `drawForeground()` method, so either one can work.  (The main difference is that graphics drawn in `QGraphicsScene::drawForeground()` would presumably show up in all associated QGraphicsViews instead of just one of them)

Comment: Oh so GraphicsView::drawForeground must just call scene::drawForeground? ... my ribbon thing actually kind of makes more sense attached to the view, but if there are no problems maybe not worth changing what i have. I only will need one view and one scene so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to override `drawForeground` in a custom scene. The trick is that `drawForeground` will be passed a `QPainter` that is set up to draw in scene coordinates but we want to draw in coordinates relative to the widget rectangle of the view, to do this you can simply set the painter's transform to the identity matrix.

Code below. I call the content rectangle of the view minus the area taken up by any scroll bars "the client rectangle" (because this is what it would be called in Win32) beyond that this code assumes that the custom scene is in one and only one view and the scene has getters/setters for showing/hiding a ribbon called "the status line".

```
// ...

QRect client_rectangle(const QGraphicsView* view) {
    auto view_rect = view->contentsRect();
    if (view->verticalScrollBar()->isVisible()) {
        auto wd = view_rect.width();
        view_rect.setWidth(wd - view->verticalScrollBar()->width());
    }
    if (view->horizontalScrollBar()->isVisible()) {
        auto hgt = view_rect.height();
        view_rect.setHeight(hgt - view->horizontalScrollBar()->height());
    }
    return view_rect;
}

// ...

void MyCustomGraphicsScene::drawForeground(QPainter* painter, const QRectF& rect) {
    QGraphicsScene::drawForeground(painter, rect);

    if (is_status_line_visible()) {
        QGraphicsView* view = views().first();
        if (!view) {
            return;
        }

        painter->setTransform(QTransform());

        auto view_rect = client_rectangle(view);
        QRect ribbon_rect = {
            view_rect.bottomLeft() - QPoint(0, 35),
            QSize(view_rect.width(), 35)
        };
        painter->fillRect(ribbon_rect, Qt::yellow);
        painter->setPen(Qt::black);
        painter->drawText(ribbon_rect, Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter, status_line_);

        painter->resetTransform();
    }
}
```